# How to find header_template for email template in magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I think header_template is XML file in which it calls header.html i find the header.html file is in `vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html` but I unable to find where is header_template file is in Magento 2

Comment: what do you want to find header.html file?

Comment: I want to add product detail in newsletter success subscription email template

Comment: so i dont know what is header_template in email template in magento2

Comment: header.html file is defined from email_templates.xml file

Comment: can you describe what is the meaning of {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} in email template

Comment: actually i make 1 template file and 1 block file and define it in layout file now i want to call layout in subscr_success.html file

Comment: {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} loads header.html in all other email templates. If you wish to add product detail in newsletter success subscription email template, you have to make changes in subscr_success.html file.

Comment: where is header_template file i am unable to find that file actually i think this is xml file

Answer (score 0):

`design/email/header_template` is a config path. If you go to `Content >> Configuration >> Transactional emails`, you will see you can assign a template as `Header Template`. If it is set to `Header(Default)` it will load default header.html file.

Its not an xml file.